# referring the image files from the Trdion server in Dreamweaver TBB in SDL Trdion 2011 Sp1

Tags: tridion, tridion-2011

I am trying to refer the Images from the Web server of the Tridion.

```
<img src="file://///ServerAddress.com/applications/Images/Styles/temporary.jpeg"  alt="alt text"/>
```

I have added this code my TBB.

The image is not getting displayed.

Added the same code in local html page in my machine, I am able to retrieve the that Image.

**Edit:**
Image is not getting displayed while previewing in Tridion CME.

Can any one suggest how to configure my image source path in TBB for accessing the Image.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: I think you'll need to add some more detail... "Image not getting displayed" - when? Preview? Template Builder? After publishing? Where is this image? Seems like it's not in Tridion, so when do you expect to see it? After publishing (hopefully)?

Comment: @Nuno Linhares.. Edited the question.. can you look into it..

Comment: You mention you added this code in your TBB, is that a Dreamweaver TBB and if so is it uploaded through WebDAV, and after that, is the reference to the image still the same when you open the DWT TBB in SDL Tridion? Please also note that using the file protocol for an image is rather unorthodox, preferably you should be using the HTTP protocol. IE usually accepts file://\\ for a UNC path, but Firefox only seems to support the file:///// workaround, not sure about Chrome.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using a `file://` URL, which means that you are referring to a local file ***on the machine that opens the HTML***. So when you open the HTML on the machine where you originally created it (and placed `temporary.jpg`), it will find the file locally and display it.

When you open the same HTML from any other machine, it will fail to find the file on that machine and thus won't display the image. The fact that you use `ServerAddress.com` makes no difference for that: file URLs will only resolve to file on the local machine.

If you want to ensure your images work properly for the rest of the internet too, use a more common protocol such as `http://`.